# Do editors for Ant scripts exist?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I have many ant files with more than 10000 lines. Do editors or plugins exist for Eclipse that can help me author the files, e.g. press F3 to find target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, [Eclipse has an Ant Editor](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-anteditor.htm).

> The Ant editor provides specialized features for editor Ant buildfiles. Associated with the editor is a Ant buildfile specific
>   Outline view which shows the structure of the Ant build file. It is
>   updated as you edit the buildfile
>
> The editor includes the following features:
>   - Syntax highlighting
>   - Content/code assist (including Ant specific templates)
>   - Annotations
>
> The most common way to invoke the Ant editor is to open an Ant
>   buildfile from one of the navigation views or Package Explorer using
>   pop-up menus or by clicking the file (single or double-click depending
>   on your preference settings).

When a build file is open in the Ant editor, the Outline view provides useful high-level information:

[image]

---

There is also a dedicated Ant view, which is fairly similar to the outline view (but does not require the build file to be in an editor): *Window → Show View → Other...*

[image]

Once you have opened the Ant view, you can add a buildfile to it, and the view will show targets, etc.:

[image]